# pagination not working properly in codeigniter 2.1.0 with url_suffix

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, codeigniter-2

i am using codeigniter 2.1.0 and mysql database. in my admin panel i have a page where i want to show all users with a paginating view. but it is not working. after trying a lot of things
here is my **updated** code
controller:

```
function accounts() // controller to view all users
{
    $this -> load -> library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('admin/home/accounts/');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('user')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 2;
    $config['num_links'] = 2;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<p id="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</p>';
    $offset = $this->uri->segment(4,0);
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
    $data['user_data']=$this->admin_model->all_user($config['per_page'],$offset);
    $data['links']=$this -> pagination -> create_links();
    $data['main_content']='admin/accounts';
    $this->load->view('includes/admin/admin_template',$data);
}
```

view:

```
<?php foreach ($user_data as $data) {?>
<?php echo 'Name:' . ' ' ?>
<?php echo ($data['name']).'<br/>'; ?>
<?php echo 'E-mail:' . ' ' ?>
<?php echo ($data['email']).'<br/>'; ?>
<br />
<?php } ?>
<?php echo $links;?>
```

model:

```
function all_user($per_page,$offset) //shows all uer info
{
    $query = $this->db->get('user', $per_page, $offset);
    $row=$query->result_array();
    return $row;
}
```

and here is the route:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['admin']='admin/admin';
```

i have used the .htaccess mod_rewrite to remove my index.php and the $config['url_suffix']='.html' to add a suffix of .html which makes the url look like this
 `'http://localhost/project/admin/home/accounts.html'`
 instead of 
`'http://localhost/project/index.php/admin/home/accounts'`
 but if i remove the url_suffix in my config.php

```
*/

$config['url_suffix'] = '';

/*
```

the pagination works fine. but i want to use url_suffix

```
*/

$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';

/*
```

but if i do so, the pagination doesn't work, and shows 404 page not found error. how do i fix this issue?

Comment: Whats the url when you click on next page

Comment: @sabari http://localhost/project/admin/home/accounts.html/2

Comment: Will it work if you take localhost/project/admin/home/accounts.php/2

Comment: @sabari,no it won't work.in the url localhost is the server project is the folder that contains whole project, admin is a subdomain containing the admin controller, home is the class and accounts is the function of the home class.the '.html' is just an extra suffix that codeigniter provides if i configure it to.it doesn't matter what the sufffix is '.html'/'.php'/'.asp' or none, the functionality remains the same.

Comment: Can you paste your router config

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = "site";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['admin']='admin/admin';

Comment: @Shabib what's the link users supposed to click ? and what's the actual link created by pagination class ?

Comment: @motto users supposed click in the 123>(paginated links) and the links should show the next/previous db items fetched accordingly.

Comment: Can you try this one in your router $route['admin/(:any)']='admin/admin'; I am not sure . Any way can you  try

Comment: @Shabib i mentioned by saying "link" the address should link point in "href" part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see lots of issues in your code. But 1st thing 1st.

Put

```
$this->uri->segment(4)
```

in your query in the offset.

Update: if you haven't done `mod_rewrite`, then add 'index.php' to your `$config['base_url']`.

E.g. 
    `$config['base_url']=base_url().'index.php/admin/....';`

add your path in above code.

Comment: i have tried that, but still it doesn't change anything :( @itachi

Comment: i have used the .htaccess mod_rewrite to remove my index.php and the $config['url_suffix']='.html' to add a suffix of .html

Comment: thank you man. i didn't get your answer first, but now i have figured it out. i just had to change $config['base_url'] = base_url().'admin/home/accounts/'...thanks alot

Comment: Also `base_url()` takes parameters, I think much nicer is this `base_url('admin/home/accounts/')`

Answer (score 3):

`$config['base_url'] = site_url('admin/home/accounts');`

in this line you need a backslas at the end  like

`$config['base_url'] = site_url('admin/home/accounts/');`

**Update**

add this to ur controller in your way

```
$data['links']=$this->pagination->create_links();
```

**Update**
A crazy idea though i know less about codeigniter.

Switch between your model and controller. Are you sure What you call controller is controller in your code? same ques for model.

**Update**
My apologies, your base url should be

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url('admin/home/accounts/index/');
```

Comment: if you have already tried these then why don't you update the code. In this issue I support itachi. there are lots of issues in your code. there is no single solution that can solve this problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

in system -> Pagination.php file (default settings)

```
class CI_Pagination {

var $base_url           = ''; // The page we are linking to
var $prefix             = ''; // A custom prefix added to the path.
var $suffix             = ''; // A custom suffix added to the path.
.
.
}
```

**$config['suffix'] ="example"**

Url_suffix for your pagination ..........

Comment: tried to format your code (not overly successful ;-) - please edit and improve